# Libraries for python that can perform various actions on an opened exe window

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a executable which when opened has a set of buttons and fields where I can enter text and submit buttons, after submitting a button which would in turn open another window and I can enter further valid text into the available fields and then submit another button on this window.

Is this possible to do in python? If so what would be the appropriate libraries that I can use to perform such actions?

The executable is available locally on my PC. So far I was able to open the .exe using the `subprocess.call` for now and finding ways to perform actions[entering text into fields, submitting button, checking text boxes etc] on the opened window.

I know that selenium can be used but I just wanted to know if it can be done using purely just python.

Comment: Autoit might be helpful. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Answer (score 0):

this won't work for everything, but might work for your needs

https://code.google.com/p/swapy/